# Logging and Spring Rest MVC app

Tags: java, spring, rest, logging, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring rest application, where I have spring rest controllers in the front, spring services in middle and spring jpa repositories behind the services. The rest controllers simply delegate the request to the service layer. Now, the question is, I can log any problems or information messages in either services layer or in controllers layer, or I can keep both of them clean and use aop approach to capture and log data into a log file. 
I am not able to decide what is the best approach, and why. Please, give me some suggestions if you have any. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to deal with this is to have an instance of the **Logger** class in every single layer.

for exemple:

```
public class EmployeeService {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeService.class);
}

public class EmployeeController {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeController.class);
}
```

- The code is much more clean
- You have the possibilty to do logs inside class methods, knowing that AOP approch does not allow it.

Answer (score 1):

Using AOP approach you have to know that new extra classes will be created with additional logic that provides logging functionality into your classes. And exactly this new classes (proxies) will be used instead of yours. This approach has some issues, for example when one method that annotated to write logs calls another one that also annotated in the similar way - in such case the second method won't write logs.

According to performance both approaches are pretty similar except more classes in memory using AOP.

Also, using AOP you can just make a log before or after method invocation, but what if you need to log something inside method?

I suggest to use simple way and declare logger in classes. In this case your code will be more understandable and you will have better flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

It's good approach to user own logger object per each class, first of all you definitely know where log was initialized and second you can flexible configure process of log.